# my bootstrap container is on top of the other

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, containers

I'm developing a homepage that has, so far, 2 bootstrap containers. What happens is, the second one is appearing on top of the first, instead of after it. What am I doing wrong here?

```
   <!-- hero cover -->
<div class="container-fluid hero-cover">

  <img src="images/cover-odonto.jpg" class="img-responsive">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 cover-text">
        <h1>Some Text</h1>
        <h3> Some secondary text</h3>
    </div> <!-- / col -->
  </div>  <!-- / row -->

    <!-- pricing tables -->
    <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-6">
            <ul class="price">
              <li></li>
              <li></li>
              <li></li>            
            </ul>
          </div> <!-- / col -->

          <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-6">
            <ul class="price">
              <li></li>
              <li></li>
              <li></li>              
            </ul>
          </div> <!-- / col -->
    </div><!-- / row -->

 </div> <!-- / container -->


<!-- beneficios -->

<div class="container beneficios-table">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <p><h2>Some title here</h2></p>
    </div> <!-- / col -->
  </div> <!-- / row -->

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <p><h3>Another Title</h3></p>
      <p><h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</h4></p>
    </div> <!-- / col -->
  </div> <!-- / row -->

</div> <!-- / container -->
```

And the css:

```
/* Nav --------------------- */
.logo-odonto {
    max-width: 200px;
}


.navbar-header {
    height: 100px;
}


/* Cover --------------------- */

.hero-cover {
    position: relative;
} 

.cover-text {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 10%;
    left: 6%;
}

.text-white {
    color: #ffffff;
}


/* Pricing --------------------- */



/* Style the list */
.price {
    list-style-type: none;
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
    transition: 0.3s;
    background-color: white;
    position: absolute;
    right: 5px;
    left: 5px;
    top: -100px;

}

/* Add shadows on hover */
.price:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 8px 12px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2)
}

/* Pricing header */
.price .price-header {
    background-color: orange;
    color: white;
    font-size: 25px;
}

/* List items */
.price li {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}


/* The "Sign Up" button */
.button {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px 25px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 18px;
}




/* Beneficios e Diferenciais --------------------- */

.beneficios-table {
    background-color: white;
    padding: 10rem;
    position: relative;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Your `col-md-5` do not add up to 12, you could change them to `col-md-6` or add 2 blank `col-md-1`as I have done below:

```html
<!-- hero cover -->
<div class="container-fluid hero-cover">

  <img src="images/cover-odonto.jpg" class="img-responsive">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 cover-text">
        <h1>Some Text</h1>
        <h3> Some secondary text</h3>
    </div> <!-- / col -->
  </div>  <!-- / row -->

    <!-- pricing tables -->
    <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-1"></div>
          <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-6">
            <ul class="price">
              <li></li>
              <li></li>
              <li></li>            
            </ul>
          </div> <!-- / col -->

          <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-6">
            <ul class="price">
              <li></li>
              <li></li>
              <li></li>              
            </ul>
          </div> <!-- / col -->
          <div class="col-md-1"></div>
       </div><!-- / row -->

 </div> <!-- / container -->


<!-- beneficios -->

<div class="container beneficios-table">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <p><h2>Some title here</h2></p>
    </div> <!-- / col -->
  </div> <!-- / row -->

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <p><h3>Another Title</h3></p>
      <p><h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</h4></p>
    </div> <!-- / col -->
  </div> <!-- / row -->

</div> <!-- / container -->`
```

Comment: Oh thanks for that. I actually added a  col-md-offset-1. But the other container (with the beneficios-table) is still on top of this one.

Comment: What's your styling script?

Comment: `z-index` specifies the order of stacking, kinda like bring to front and send to back, have you tried working without it? To have a better understanding,  [read more here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp)